# Разработка модуля ядра Linux на ассемблере

Tags: linux, ассемблер, ядро

В Linux'е не шибко спец, однако есть такая задача: разработать модуль ядра...
Вот, к примеру, простой hello world (NASM), однако как его собрать и запустить? Именно как **модуль ядра**!

```
BITS 32

GLOBAL      main
EXTERN      printk

SECTION     .data

Hello       db  'Hello world!',0

SECTION     .text

main:

        push    Hello
        call    printk
        add     esp,4

        ret
```

После компиляции **nasm**'ом **gcc** собирать его отказывается, говоря, что понятия не имеет ни о каком **printk**.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы собрать и запустить этот код именно как *модуль ядра*?

---

**upd 05.06.2017**: Создал несколько файлов, однако это всё не работает. Где косяки и как их поправить – не знаю... :((

Может, кто помочь с этим?

**module.c**

```
#include <linux/module.h>  // Необходим для любого модуля ядра

extern void MyProc(void);
int init_module(void)
{
  MyProc();
  return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
}
```

**main.asm**

```
BITS 32

GLOBAL      MyProc
EXTERN      printk

SECTION     .data

Hello       db  'Hello word!',0

SECTION     .text

MyProc:

        push    Hello
        call    printk
        add esp,4

        ret
```

**makefile**

```
obj-m += test.o
test-objs := module.o main.o
$(KBUILD_EXTMOD)/main.o: main.asm
    nasm -f elf -o $@ $^
```

**compile.sh**

```
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r` SUBDIRS=$PWD modules
```

Что не так?

---

Хотя... вроде заработало...

Только теперь непонятно как это запустить...

Пишу **sudo insmod test.ko** – в ответ тишина. Где **Hello world!** ?
Файла /var/log/messages у меня нет вообще...

Comment: Например, спросить у гугла "как разрабатывать модули ядра Linux". Который может показать, в том числе, [нечто вроде](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-linux_kernel_01/). Но не надейтесь, что там будет волшебный рецепт, который ответит на вопрос в один клик мышкой. Таки придётся сначала изучать архитектуру ядра Linux, процессы сборки, зависимости, инструменты, и проделать много другой скучной и "неинтересной" работы.

Comment: @PinkTux, мне не нужно ***знать всё*** о модулях ядра "одним кликом мышки". Мне нужно **просто скомпилировать и собрать этот код и выполнить его как модуль ядра** (ну или если я добавлю туда пару привилегированных вещей, прога не должна падать). ВСЁ. Я думаю, что должен быть способ сделать это если не одним или двумя кликами,то достаточно просто... Приведённая ссылка вообще мне ни о чём не говорит. Я это уже находил. Там даже нет ассемблера совсем.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13668403/4827341

Comment: Вообще вам придется это все изучить. В главе 16 например как раз рассказано про сборку. Если в кратце, вы должны создать Makefile, написать в него строчку `obj-m: module.o` и запустить `make -C/lib/modules/версия-ядра/build SUBDIRS=текущая-директория modules` и ... у вас так ничего не выйдет, надо читать дальше. Например у вашего модуля нет точки входа. `main` не является точкой входа для модулей ядра. А помимо точки входа надо соблюсти еще десяток правил

Comment: @Mike, в какой **главе 16**?

Comment: @JinX Которая к той первой главе, на которую вам дали ссылку в самом начале. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-linux_kernel_16/index.html

Comment: **Файла /var/log/messages у меня нет вообще...** Расположение файла лога может отличаться в разных дистрибутивах. Более того, даже сама система логирования может быть разной.  Для того, что бы понять, что за лог-демон работает у Вас,  для начала выполните команду *ps ax | grep log*. Если увидите там rsyslogd  - значит это Ваш лог-демон. Если что-то другое (dsyslig, syslog-ng...) - значит у Вас такой. Далее лезем в каталог /etc и ищем там подкаталог вида rsyslod.d и в нём - файл конфигурации. А уже в этом файле будет путь к Вашему файлу сислога.

Comment: Потому что у вас уровень логгирования стоит H, а обычно это число.

Answer (score 8):

> как его собрать и запустить? Именно как модуль ядра!

Основное отличие сборки любого приложения для адресного пространства пользователя от сборки модуля для адресного пространства ядра, заключается в том, что приложение - самостоятельная сущность, а модуль - работает под управлением ядра.

Из этого следует, что для компиляции модуля Вам нужно иметь исходные тексты  (как минимум - заголовки) ядра, а для его компоновки (т.е. получения файла *.ko) необходимы объектные коды самого ядра.

Существует определённая технология сборки самого ядра и его модулей. С ней вкратце можно ознакомиться вот здесь:

[Разработка модулей ядра Linux (Алексей Соловьев)](http://www.linuxrsp.ru/artic/linux_kernel_module_guide_development.html)

Более профессионально всё изложено вот здесь:

[Разработка модулей ядра Linux (Олег Цилюрик)](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/views/global/libraryview.jsp?site_id=40&contentarea_by=Linux&sort_by=Date&sort_order=1&start=1&end=36&topic_by=-1&product_by=&type_by=%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5&show_abstract=true&search_by=%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0&industry_by=&series_title_by=) (цикл статей на IBM developerWorks)

Но там 36 глав... Вам для разбега хватит и первой главы:

[Разработка модулей ядра Linux: Часть 1. Первые шаги](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-linux_kernel_01/index.html)

И хотел бы заметить, что ядро почти на 100% написано на С. На ассемблере пишут только те части ядра, которые существенно зависят от архитектуры. Например - функции работы с регистрами устройств ввода/вывода в драйверах.

Comment: А может, есть какие-то исходники, которые содержат модуль на Си для подключения asm-кода, болванку asm-кода, makefile и compile.sh?

Comment: Сейчас добавлю в первое сообщение что у меня получается... Но это не работает. Можете поправить?

Comment: Добавил, см. выше...

Comment: Вроде заработало. Только теперь новый вопрос: как это всё запустить? Пишу **sudo insmod test.ko** – запускается, а в ответ тишина. Где я могу увидеть свой **Hello world!** ?

Comment: @JinX в `dmesg`?

Comment: @D-side, спасибо! :)) А в консоль никак нельзя выводить эти сообщения (модифицировав код asm-файла)?

Comment: @JinX без понятия, никогда таким не занимался. Интуитивно, наверное, можно попытаться найти в ядре `stdout` текущего процесса. Быстрый поиск [натолкнул на это](http://www.faqs.org/docs/kernel/x1111.html).

Comment: **А в консоль никак нельзя выводить эти сообщения** - для этого в ядре есть макрос printk(KERN_ERR "Ваше сообщение\n"); Обратите внимание, что синтаксис этого макроса не совпадает с синтаксисом функции printf.